# Gmail tablet like Actionbar items

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem, android-toolbar

I'm trying to build an app with a split `actionbar/toolbar` like in the Gmail app.

Is there any view element for this behaviour or do I have to write such a toolbar myself?

The search icon is moving with the master `fragment` when opening the `slidingDrawer`.

[image: Closed drawer]

[image: Opened drawer]

Comment: Here's the good example: http://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/supporting-phones-and-tablets-v1

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish this you can add one of the new [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) widgets to each of your fragments layouts. The new Toolbar class was designed to be much more flexible than a traditional Actionbar and will work well in this split design. [This post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) is a good overview for implementing a standalone Toolbar. For posterity's sake I've included the sample code for it below.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.blah);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);

    // Set an OnMenuItemClickListener to handle menu item clicks
    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle the menu item
        return true;
        }
    });

    // Inflate a menu to be displayed in the toolbar
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.your_toolbar_menu);
}
```

Comment: Good one there! Rarely see on in Room 15 lately!

Comment: Still unable to understand.