# Change default search icon position in search view

Tags: android, material-design, searchview

I use Search view in my project for adding search ability for users. my problem is I want to change search icon position from right side of toolbar to left side.

this is my menu code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@android:string/search_go"
    android:icon="@drawable/search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:visible="true"/>
```

and this is my activity code:

```
private SearchView mSearchView;
private MenuItem searchMenuItem;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();
    mSearchView.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(Gravity.LEFT));
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(listener);
    return true;
}

SearchView.OnQueryTextListener listener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        if (query.equals("") || query.equals(" ")){
            Toast.makeText(G.context,"ابتدا یک متن برای جستجو بنویسید.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(ContentsActivity.this,SearchActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("KEYWORD", query);
        ContentsActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31295114/how-to-change-the-position-of-the-menu-item-of-the-action-bar-to-left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I found solution.
note that it is not a good solution. but it's works fine for me.

in menu_main.xml:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@android:string/search_go"
    android:icon="@drawable/search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:visible="false"/>
```

in the menu file i set the visibility of search icon to the false. so now when user clicks on my search icon in the toolbar i set the visibility to true.

```
imgCatSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mSearchView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(G.context,R.anim.m_anim);
            searchMenuItem.setVisible(true);
            mSearchView.setIconified(false);
            mSearchView.startAnimation(anim);
        }
    });
```

So when user clicks on search button in action bar the search view visibility turned to true and opened.

finally this code is for when user clicks on close button in searchView :

```
mSearchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            searchMenuItem.setVisible(false);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

in toolbar xml code,set direction to right.
like this     android:layoutDirection="rtl"

```
       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:id="@+id/basepage_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#D4AC0D"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        >
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: that's very bad approach as it will limit your Toolbar and completely change direction of everything in it .