# How to set up master detail flow + split toolbar?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to make the following two features work together:

1. Left drawer navigation
2. Separate toolbars for each fragment on the screen

You can see this working on apps like GMAIL:
[image]

See how each pane has it's own toolbar? What I mean by this is that the "Search" icon is right-aligned to the left fragment. On top of this, I also need this in order to set a title to each pane individually.

This would be very easy to do without the left drawer navigation. You just get rid of the toolbar on the `Activity` and use one toolbar on each `Fragment`, done.
But with the left drawer navigation things become a bit messy, you need a `toolbar` on the `activity` in order to implement it.

One possible solution I was thinking of was using inner fragments for the left pane like this:
[image]

This should work in theory, but I've used inner fragments in the past and they are NO fun. I would really like to avoid them if possible.
Also, the designers are thinking of removing the left pane navigation in the future so, I would have to do a lot of refactoring for nothing...

(PS: I know you can call `setHasOptionsMenu` on the fragment to create a "combined" toolbar items from activity+any visible fragment but that's not really what I'm looking for)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gmail tablet like Actionbar items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31182533/gmail-tablet-like-actionbar-items)

Answer (score 0):

Well I've been able to solve this and avoid inner-fragments altogether :D

This is how I set it up, in case someone has the same problem:

1. Each fragment manages its own toolbar
2. The activity manages the navigation drawer

Add this method to your `activity`

```
private ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;

    public void setupNavDrawer(Toolbar toolbar) {
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(this);
    toggle.syncState();
}
```

And call it from the `Fragment` whose toolbar should have the hamburger menu

This is how my `activity_main.xml` looks like:

https://gist.github.com/feresr/66aaf9c92173d6414e4ba9df7366f77c

This is working for me, let me know if you have any doubts I'll try to help you :)